# I am trying to create a hook to search and filter through data, but it's going into an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to create a hook that takes in a set of props, including a searchQuery, filters, and searchKeys (for searching through data). It will then filter through the data based on the searchQuery and filters and return the data that is filtered.
The problem is that useEffect is going into an infinite loop and I'm not sure why.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type PropsType<T> = {
  searchQuery?: string;
  filters?: Array<{ filter: string, filterKey: keyof T }>;
  searchKeys?: (keyof T)[];
} & (
  { searchQuery: string, searchKeys: (keyof T)[] } |
  { filters: Array<{ filter: string, filterKey: keyof T }> }
)

const useHandleData = <T>(props: PropsType<T>, data: Array<T>) => {
  const { searchQuery, filters = [], searchKeys = [] } = props;
  const [displayData, setDisplayData] = useState<Array<T>>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let filteredData = data;
    if (searchQuery && searchKeys.length > 0) {
      filteredData = searchThroughData(filteredData, searchQuery, searchKeys);
    }
    if (filters.length > 0) {
      filters.forEach(filter => {
        filteredData = filterThroughData(filteredData, filter.filter, filter.filterKey);
      });
    }
    setDisplayData(filteredData);
  }, [searchQuery, filters, data]);

  return { displayData };
}

const searchThroughData = <T>(data: Array<T>, searchQuery: string, searchKeys: (keyof T)[]) => {
  if (!searchQuery || searchKeys.length === 0) return data;
  return data.filter(item => {
    for (let key of searchKeys) {
      if (item[key]?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toString().toLowerCase())) return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
}

const filterThroughData = <T>(data: Array<T>, filter: string, filterKey: keyof T) => {
  if (!filter || !filterKey) return data;
  return data.filter(item => item[filterKey] === filter);
}

export { useHandleData };
```

```
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("")
  const [filterQuery, setFilterQuery] = useState<{ filter: string, filterKey: keyof item }[]>([])

  const { displayData } = useHandleData({
    searchQuery: searchQuery,
    searchKeys: ['name', 'itemName'],
    filters: filterQuery
  }, itemList)
```

Comment: Please provide the code that calls the hook and causes the infinite loop. (By editing your question).